# Recover Deleted Drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I had two drives:

A **C drive** that contained the OS files.

A **D drive** that contained my personal files.

The **D drive** was made out by shrinking **C drive** and creating a new volume out of the unallocated space.

I accidentally deleted the **D drive**, which now shows as **Unallocated space**.

**Will I be able to restore the drive, i.e. D drive.**?

I have had certain **Data recovery software** try the same. I am able to **Preview** the files in the Data Recovery Application, but have not proceeded with the restoration part.

**I have not restarted my system yet.**

**I have not done anything to the Unallocated space**. I haven't even closed the **Disk Management** window.

Comment: I understand that there is a meme involved in dropping any verbs after the word 'accidentally', but in this case, the missing verb will be rather important. the differance between "formated", "removed", "dropped", etc makes a huge differance in what you need to do to try to recover the data. you will need another disk with enough capacity to store all the files that had been on D. you cannot recover files to the same drive they were removed from. since I'm guessing you removed the partition, you probably want to use Testdisk.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Thanks. I would still call it accidental. That is because, the D had three different non contiguous portions when seen from the Disk Management. I right clicked on one of them (a 5 GB portion), thinking that I would deleting that alone, but I was wrong.

Comment: then testdisk is for you. and yes, 'deleted' was the verb I was looking for. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step good luck. from what you say, you have an excellent chance of recovering the partition.

Comment: @FrankThomas: I hope that wasn't sarcastic.

Comment: of course not. the link should give you a good howto on TestDisk. I've used it to recover partitions before. as long as the disk is mechanically healthy, and no data has been overwritten as you say, you should not have any trouble recovering the partition. there are never any guarantees with data recovery though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great tool that I have used in the past for recovering deleted data.  It is called [FTK Imager](http://www.accessdata.com/support/product-downloads).

You will have to fill out a form to download it, but they don't sell your info.

Once you have installed FTK Imager open the program and click on **File> Add Evidence Item...> Physical Drive> Select the drive that the partition was originally on**

Now you will be able to browse through the files in the tree on the left hand side.

When you find what you need (which is probably everything), just right click and export the data to a new folder.

This may not be the best way to recover your data from a deleted partition, but it is the way I know to recover your data for you.

Comment: If happen to be affiliated with the product, please disclose that information in the answer.